# Removing a comma after list ends

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I'm trying to read from a cvs file and write the output to a txt document:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('C:\Python33\excel.csv', newline=''), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
text_file = open("C:\Python33\output.txt", "w")
c = ", "

for row in reader:
    text_file.write(', '.join(row))
    text_file.write(c)

#reader.close()
text_file.close()
```

The current output looks like this:

```
current: `beef, chicken, corn, cheese, yogurt, hippo,`

desired: `beef, chicken, corn, cheese, yogurt, hippo`
```

I want to remove the comma at the end of the list, I'm thinking of an if statement to check if I'm at the end of the list? But I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Remove the `text_file.write(c)` line.

Comment: There's no `'\n'`: `text_file.write(', '.join(row) + '\n')` on the previous line.

Comment: Could you fix your indentation? What goes in the `for row in reader:` loop?

Comment: I fixed it, so it makes more sense.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `excel.csv` file?

Comment: Excel contents: http://gyazo.com/d6cb35b4a2bed017ca7054ec231c89f0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store all of your lines in a list, and then concatenate them together with `join`.

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('C:\Python33\excel.csv', newline=''), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
text_file = open("output.txt", "w")

lines = []
for row in reader:
    lines.append(', '.join(row))

output = ", ".join(lines)
print(output)
```

Result:

```
beef, chicken, corn, cheese, yogurt, hippo
```

Comment: This worked, thank you for the response. The other people didn't quite understand what my problem was :/ +1!

Answer (score 0):

you just have to `Remove the text_file.write(c) line.`
**It is just causing the extra comma .**

Comment: I tried removing that line. It bunches all of the rows together without a comma. txt file:  "beefchickencorncheeseyogurthippo"